# Quickblox unregisterSubscriptionForUniqueDeviceIdentifier issue

Tags: quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox iOS SDK v2.4.6. (on starter tier)

The "unregisterSubscriptionForUniqueDeviceIdentifier" method seems to work fine as long as the app hasn't been in the background for more than a couple of hours (i.e. registering the subscription with QB works and you can see the subscription in the QB admin panel, and unregistering it removes it - but unregistering fails if the app is in background more than a couple of hours).

I initially thought this may be due to session timeout, but in QB 2.4+ ssession handling is automatic (I have also checked for a valid session on re-launching the app from the background and it does exist).

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on here?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: In the end I just used the iOS unregisterForRemoteNotifications without calling the QB unregisterSubscriptionForUniqueDeviceIdentifier - this works (it's up to the QB server to query the apple feedback server and remove/deactivate devices which are reported as no longer in use)